# What modern camera bodies can use Minolta Maxxum Lenses?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses, minolta

I have an old Minolta Maxxum, is there a camera DSLR body that will take all the lenses from the Maxxum available ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. Any [digital camera with an A-mount](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?mount=alpha) will accept them directly. The Sony A68 is the latest such model and uses an APS-C sensor so it will crop the field of view by 1.5X, meaning all your lenses will become less wide but they will still work. To preserve the field-of-view, you can use a full-frame model such as the Sony SLT-A99V.

There is another good option and that is to with a Sony E-mount mirrorless camera and an additional adapter. These some in two varieties and coverage-size, one with Phase-Detect AF which will allow the camera to also perform autofocus with your Maxxum lenses. Some newer models can do it without the Phase-Detect adapter because they have built-in Phase-Detect AF.

Comment: May want to add "A-mount" or "dSLT" to Alpha in your first sentence, given that both A-mount (alpha) and E-mount (NEX) cameras now [_both_ come under the Alpha label](http://www.sony.com/electronics/interchangeable-lens-camera-products/t/interchangeable-lens-cameras).

Comment: Note that when using the adapter with built-in Phase-Detect AF and non-AF lenses the lenses must first be brought fairly close to the correct focus setting manually. The adapter can't, for example, bring a lens physically set at infinity to focus near the MFD or vice-versa.